# Column Sorting in Django Admin

Tags: django

Hey I have a model `UserProfile` which has a OneToOneField relationship to the model `User`. In the adminpage I use `list_display` property to display some of the fields of UserProfile in the same place where `User` is displayed. They are displayed well but unfortunately they are not sortable like the models from `User`. I can click on the column heading in order to sort the columns which belong to `User` but not the ones that are from `UserProfile` how do you make them clickable and sortable?

Comment: The OP is referring to column sorting, not ordering of the queryset for the model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to add the [`admin_order_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) property to your columns.

Comment: any idea how I could define `admin_order_field`  for a regular model field? (I'm familiar with the AdminModel and the use of  `admin_order_field`  for custom columns)